# Which Windows XP hosted virtual machine can I use for OS X guests?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

I´m a java developer and my current notebook runs WinXP. I want to buy a MacBook, maybe an AirBook. But before i buy a expensive machine, I need to know if all my needs (both professional and personal) and desires will be met. So, are there any winxp hosted virtual machine to use with OS X as guest?

EDIT: The initial questino got truncated. Making it clear: i want to test my enviroment in OSX before buying a real computer. Then if all works, i will buy a OSX installed machine from Apple.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/4409/how-can-i-run-osx-under-windows , http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-osx-within-windows-virtual-pc , http://superuser.com/questions/15184/running-iphone-sdk-on-mac-os-x-server-in-vmware-a-pc/15191#15191

Comment: I asked first. :-D So, they are the duplicates. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any legal way to run Mac OS X in a Virtual Machine to the exception of running Mac OS X Server in VMWare Fusion (already a Mac product). So you won't really be able to try Mac OS X before you buy.

However, to help with dissipate your doubts about having all you need:

1. You can always run Windows Natively on your Mac using [Bootcamp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/). It's a dual boot solution but it works really well. So if you don't like Mac OS X you don't have to throw anything away.
2. There are three Virtual Machine package you can use in Mac OS X to be able to run Windows applications side by side with Mac application. In order of preference (totally in my Opinion) [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/), [Parallels Desktop for Mac](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop) and [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). The first two have very good OSX integration.

Comment: Great response. This is what I was attempting to type.

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't make sense as asked.

If your asking what VM packages to use then the choices are VMWare Fusion or Parallels. IMO Parallels 4.0 has stolen back the crown of "best VM choice" from Fusion due to its better usage of resources.

if you're asking what XP install to use then I'd recommend the 32-bit version of Windows XP Professional. The benefits of the 64-bit version are marginal, if any, and IMO far outweighed by the niggling compatibility issues you are likely to run into with 64-bit XP.

If you're asking if there's anywhere you can download pre-installed XP VM's, then no there isn't, at least not legally.

Comment: +1 Question is pretty unclear, good job on trying to answer it!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot host OS X in a virtual machine, except using VMWare fusion **under** OS X, using OS X Server as a guest.