# Any Way to run Mac OSX software under Windows?

Tags: macos, mac, virtualization, wine, emulation

I know that you [cannot run MacOSX](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/) within a virtual machine, but I am curious if there is something similar to [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) that emulates MacOSX enough to allow running some MacOSX software under Windows.  Maybe even through application virtualization?

**Update**: The site [AlternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/) has a lot of suggestions of alternative applications on different platforms.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific OS X application you want on Windows?

Comment: A few applications, specifically iWork.

Comment: Well, it's not impossible to run OS X on a virtual machine, or even run it full time on your PC (see the [OSx86 Project](http://www.osx86project.org/)), but from experience I can tell you it's not very easy at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, no.

There is a project to run Mac binaries on Windows, but when I found it, about a year ago, it was a long way from reliably running simple Mach-O binaries, let alone emulating all the frameworks most GUI applications require (Cocoa, CoreImage and the likes).. I don't recall the name of the project, and it didn't seem very active at the time

There is [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/Info/), "an open source project which aims to implement a cross-platform Objective-C API similar to that described by Apple Inc.'s Cocoa documentation" - but I don't think this is what you're after..

Again, no, there is nothing like WINE for running Mac software on Windows, and really I doubt there ever will be.

The closest you'll likely get is software being ported (via recompilation, which will involve a lot of modification to the source code), and as John T says, there's plenty of equivalent software which will be *far* better integrated with Windows..

Answer (score 6):

To date there really is no application which does this well, although I'm sure there have been a lot of attempts. Your best bet is to find alternative software. **Most** software nowadays has a counterpart which does pretty much the same thing on a different operating system.

Comment: I love downvotes without comments. If you're going to say my answer is wrong, prove it, i'd love to see OSX apps run on win32.

Comment: John T, look at your answer (which mysteriously got 5 points) compared to the best answer, which is far more interesting and informative than yours. Though we do not expect questioners to know how to ask open-ended questions, we do upvote answerers who know how to inform on-topic. Though with 39K points, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

There's PearPC, which operates and acts as a virtual machine of sorts.  This will allow you to install OS X in it's own environment and then run that from inside windows. I believe it's all about powerPC emulation so you may be limited to older versions of OS X... like Tiger and earlier. [PearPC](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/)

Then there's the OSX86 (Hackintosh) route.  This is where you grab one of the OSX installation  disk images online which have been modified to install on intel & amd PC's. This is the route I chose.  I'm running a Dell Vostro 1500 notebook with dual boot installations of OSX Snow Leopard & Windows 7 Ultimate.  I love it and would actually consider OSX to be my main OS on this system. [InsanelyMac](http://www.insanelymac.com/)

Answer (score 0):

VMware Fusion is the only system I find it working. But, you cannot run just the application on the windows machine, like the Crossover does on the Mac, you have to run it in a virtual environment—which turn out to be less than convenient. If you want to totally rely on mac applications, turning your pc to Hackintosh, as suggested above, could be a choice. But, the process is often painful: once, I destroyed the boot sector of my pc trying to install a Hackintosh.