# Can I run Mac software on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, macos, emulation

Is there a way to run Mac software without using a virtual machine?

**Note:** Though there is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/12719/any-way-to-run-mac-osx-software-under-windows), it is pretty outdated; the update, while more recent, does not actually answer that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, short of creating a virtual machine within Windows 7, or just installing OS X onto PC hardware and dual-booting, both of which are very possible and even easy these days, there still isn't any way to do this.

The answer given by dbr in that thread you linked to still very much applies, probably even more so today, since more and more Mac apps are relying on the libraries included with OS X to even be functional, rather than each developer rewriting functionality, that the OS provides for free, from scratch.

Comment: Also, installing OS X on non-Apple hardware is against their license. Even when using virtualization tools. So while this is technically possible, it is most probably illegal, even if you own Mac or OS X.

Comment: @haimg Didn't they change that with newest version of Mac OS (10.7)? Also what about server versions? If I remember correctly, the virtualization of them has been allowed for quite some time.

Comment: @AndrejaKo But still only on Apple hardware. The [license](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx1072.pdf) states: *> additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MacinCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/).  I have never used it, nor do I know anyone who has...  but the theory is you have access to a Mac through the internet.