# Is there a way to virtualize Mac OSX in Windows?

Tags: macos, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Mac OSX within Windows Virtual PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-osx-within-windows-virtual-pc)

I have heard rumors that there is a way to run Mac OSX Server in a Virtual Machine in windows.  I know this is not exactly Legal.
I want to do this to try out what it is like to develop applications for the iPhone but without the huge investment of buying a MAC.

Comment: The performance will probably be atrocious. At least that was the case for me.

Comment: Buy a Mac Mini,...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try PearPC

http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/
http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/PearPC.html

Comment: +1 seems like the only way without "hacking" things.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a look at this same/similar question: [How to run Mac OSX within Windows Virtual PC](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-osx-within-windows-virtual-pc)

Jonathan Sampson answered:

> Can you run OS X on Windows? Yes,
>   apparently you can with [PearPC](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-osx-within-windows-virtual-pc).
>   Is it legal? Well, that is another
>   question on its own.
>
> While it is possible (which is what
>   you asked), there are certain
>   limitations:
>
> > *While the CPU emulation may be slow (1/500th or 1/15th), the speed of
> >     emulated hardware is hardly impacted
> >     by the emulation; the emulated
> >     hard-drive and CDROM e.g. are very
> >     fast, especially with OS that support
> >     bus-mastering (Linux, Darwin, Mac OS X
> >     do). A lot of unimplementated features
> >     are fatal (i.e. will abort PearPC).
> >     Timings are very still a little bit
> >     inaccurate. Don't rely on benchmarks
> >     made in the client. PearPC lacks a
> >     save/restore machine-state feature. No
> >     LBA48 (but LBA). Currently no support
> >     for hard disks greater than 128 GiB.
> >     Disks > 4GiB are not tested very
> >     well.*
>
> [image]