# Can I install Mac OS in windows through VMware workstation?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

Can I install Mac OS in windows through VMware workstation ?
I have VMware workstation software. I want to install Mac OS in Windows 7. Can I?

Comment: Its possible; But only on Apple hardware;  There exists hacks to allow it but I can't link to those for obvious reasons.

Comment: I can understand

Comment: Dupes: [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc), [Is there a way to virtualize Mac OSX in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/48323/is-there-a-way-to-virtualize-mac-osx-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MacOS runs on Intel processors it is possible: http://www.sysprobs.com/mac-windows-featured-post

Comment: I also found this 
http://www.sysprobs.com/vmware-workstation-8-0-8-0-1-unlocker-to-run-mac-os-x-guest-in-windows-7

Comment: The legality of these hacks are questionable at best.  The license does not authorize you to run OS X on anything except Apple hardware.

Comment: "It is most likely legal." ...and the source, "Hagar" on the insanelymac forums, seems like a reputable lawyer.  ;)

Comment: this one also use full
http://store.apple.com/us/product/HE070LL/A/parallels-desktop-9-for-mac-5-users?fnode=000104090a

Comment: Sure but it seems to be the "opposite" way: "Run Windows on your Mac!"