# Can Snow Leopard be run inside Windows 7 using VMware?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-player

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc)

Can a PC running Windows 7 with VMware, run Snow Leopard in a VMware virtual machine?  Has it been done before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is currently not allowed by Apple's Terms of Service, it is not officially supported by VMware and others. You can [run OS X Server](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2008/06/virtual-leopard.html), but also only on original Apple Hardware.

There was an open Source Project once ([PearPC](http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/), for emulating PowerPC on Intel) but I think that is dead now.

Comment: Sadly but true, Apple doesn't want to power other hardware with their OS

Comment: *cough* hackintosh *cough*