# Virtualize Mac OS X Using Virtual Box or Microsoft Virtual PC

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc)

Hi. 
I know there are a lot of tutorials and stuffs telling how to install MAC OSX on windows, using vmware, like [this one](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Vmware) 
But anyone knows a way to install it using Virtual Box or even microsoft virtual pc ? 
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-osx-within-windows-virtual-pc

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Mac OS X EULA not allowing virtualization (only for Mac OS X Server and that only on a Mac) VirtualBox does not support Mac OS X / Server as a guest system. The only way to make this work (technically) is to do a Hackintosh install within VirtualBox which I cannot really recommend. You'd be using several pieces of software that were explicitly not meant to be used together. You experience of Mac OS X would be nowhere near the real thing.

Don't know about VPC, I stay away from MS products, but the totally b0rked way of a Hackintosh install might be feasable, but is likewise not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

There is no virtualization software that can run the Mac OS X operating system. This is most likely because Apple does not want anyone to be able to run their OS on anything but their hardware. (as specified in their EULA and by them shutting down companies that have tried to circumvent that measure)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks. 
Remembering that using VMWare works. 
I just want to use textmate, so, I have bought a e-editor license, but I need to use it in linux, I'll try with Wine...

Comment: They have managed to get E to run natively on Linux - if you're comfortable compiling stuff yourself (I assume you would be if you want to use E/TextMate!) - http://e-texteditor.com/blog/2009/linux-progress.