# Vitualize Apple OS X

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization

I want to install Apple OS X on a virtual machine. 
My computer is somewhat old. I have Intel Pentium M 725 processor that have support for SSE2 instruction set but have no support for PAE. Is there anyway to install OS X on it?
I mean is PAE required in the processor to run a virtualized OS X using VirtualBox, VMWare or any other solution?

Comment: Three problems: (a) it's not legal, (b) it's never going to work on such antique hardware and (c) it's not a programming-related question so it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: Also, why on earth is this post tagged iphone?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it possible to run a Mac OS X installation on a virtual machine?](http://superuser.com/questions/16830/is-it-possible-to-run-a-mac-os-x-installation-on-a-virtual-machine) and/or [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc) and/or [Virtualize Mac OS X Using Virtual Box or Microsoft Virtual PC](http://superuser.com/questions/122438/virtualize-mac-os-x-using-virtual-box-or-microsoft-virtual-pc)

Answer (score 2):

The EULA of OS X only allows for installation on Apple hardware; not directly, or through a virtual machine, on a PC.

EDIT:[It appears](http://pcpro.co.uk/news/368464) that with Apple will allow you to run up to 2 virtual machines on Lion, provided the host machine is running Mac OS on a Mac computer. 
(although I'm unsure how this works as you need snow leopard in order to upgrade to lion and legally you can't run snow leopard in a virtual machine)

Comment: You're wrong...

Comment: I am? care to explain how?

Comment: OS X Server 10.6 may be used as a virtual machine guest system on a host with physical Mac hardware.

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase slightly.