# Running iPhone SDK on Mac OS X Server in VMWare on a PC

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have read somewhere (can't find the source now) that Mac OS X is only licensed to run on Apple hardware but that Mac OS X Server can run on non-Apple hardware and virtualised platforms.

I have two questions:-

1. Is this correct?
2. Can I install and run the iPhone SDK on Mac OS X Server?

Thanks...

Comment: Questions about running Mac OS X in a VM are against the [Mac OS X Software License Agreement](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macosx106.pdf) where it is stated: "you are granted a limited non-exclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a *single Apple-branded computer* at a time." Therefore, Hackintosh questions are not welcome here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) No. Mac OS X Server can **NOT** be legally run on non-Apple hardware. It **CAN** be virtualized on **Apple** hardware.

2) Yes, the iPhone SDK does install on Mac OS X Server.

Comment: I suspected as much.  What a shame.  It seems so pointless to have to get another box to do this when I already have a perfectly good box.

Comment: Diago:  No Apple OS can _LEGALLY_ run on non Apple hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Phuzion, the question was not if LEGALLY it was possible.
Yes, it is possible to run MAC OS on non-Apple hardware. I write this message with Safari running on a VMWare machine for MAC OS on Windows.