# Mac OS X for VirtualBox

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc)

How do I virtualize Mac OS X on Windows XP host with VirtualBox?

Comment: You don't. Not legally. Last time I checked, OS X's EULA states you can only virtualise it on Apple's software.

Comment: ... and also only the Server version starting with Leopard, not the regular client one.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-osx-within-windows-virtual-pc, http://superuser.com/questions/48323/is-there-a-way-to-virtualize-mac-osx-in-windows, http://superuser.com/questions/25893/can-i-run-mac-os-x-as-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine, http://superuser.com/questions/15184/running-iphone-sdk-on-mac-os-x-server-in-vmware-a-pc among many others on the sister sites.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2076) is THE thread on the subject in the VBox forums.

Basically, because it's specifically prohibited by Apple (running it virtualised on non-Apple hardware), Sun can't work on making VBox properly compatible with it. This means no Guest Additions, at the very least.

However, it has been done on a basic level by users, albeit with various questionable hacks, and the result is unstable, slow and limited (and it's worse in VMWare, apparently).

Comment: I'd say Sun _can_ do it legally, but they don't have a huge business case for that, given the limited scope for legal use.