# Apple 10.7 Lion OS on Windows 7 Using VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc)

So I do not own a Mac, and have never owned a Mac so I am not really sure how it typically works with the OS'. I am interested in purchasing either SL or Lion for the purposes of running on my Win7 box in VM using VirtualBox.

It seems that the only thing I can purchase in terms of physical media are like OS updates. You have to have Snow Leopard to install lion, and you have to have leopard to install snow leopard...am I understanding this correctly? Do I really have to go back several operating systems and keep updating forward with media for each? How far do I have to go back to end up with either Snow Leopard or Lion?

Before you wonder (which is a completely legitimate question I agree), I am not interested in purchasing the Apple system...this is simply for testing purposes for app development. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Mac OS X within Windows Virtual PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/6538/how-to-run-mac-os-x-within-windows-virtual-pc), or http://superuser.com/questions/56564/mac-os-x-for-virtualbox, or http://superuser.com/questions/218297/mac-os-x-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS X EULA forbids using it on non-"Apple branded" hardware. So there's no official way to do it. Other than that, check the excellent links provided in @techie007's comment!